# Xpath for a value of an element where value of attribute is something

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this XML. I Want to find the value of Element "Val" where the value of Attribute @Name = "User".

```html
<Root xmlns="http://schemas.business.com">
  <Parameter Name="ABC">
    <Val>False</Val>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter Name="PQ">
    <Val>Retail</Val>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter Name="User">
    <Val>False</Val>
  </Parameter>
</Root>
```

I have gone as far as getting the entire Parameter Node with //*[@Name="User"]  but I want the value of Val element.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I tried this.   `//attribute::*[contains(., 'User')]`    which got me the Attribute Value. I think I am close but missing the bit.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following *XPath* expression.

> XPath

```
/*:Root/*:Parameter[@Name="User"]/*:Val
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it, with a longer form of XPath.

`/*[local-name()='Root']/*[local-name()='Parameter' and @Name='User']/*[local-name()='Val']/text()`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another option :

```
//*[name()="Parameter"][@Name="User"]/child::*/text()
```

Output : `False`